# Azure and classic asp - showing detailed error messages

Tags: azure, asp-classic

I just moved my site with classic ASP to Azure (website), and are having some trouble getting detailed error messages - just receiving "An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator. If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error."

I've added httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" to web.xml but it does not seem to help.

I've set up http://azure.dollarkurs.no so you can see for yourselves.

Need help! :)

Answer (score 1):

[Classic ASP Website on Azure "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532099/classic-asp-website-on-azure-the-page-cannot-be-displayed-because-an-internal-s)

This should sort you out.