# When I set customErrors mode="Off" in azure I do not get the error information

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, custom-errors

I get this message:

> "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

my web.config

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

my Web.Debug.config/Web.Release.config

```
<customErrors mode="Off" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
  <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solve the problem

```
<system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Awesome! Can you mark it as an answer so that other folks can benefit from it? Thanks!