# Unable to access my X509Certificate2's PrivateKey In Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate

I have my X509Certificate stored in a database (in `byte[]`) so that my application can retrieve the certificate and use it to sign my JWTs.

My x509Certificate is passed off a .pfx file that I generated on my machine, however now it sits in a database as a string of bytes.

My application works perfectly fine locally when I run it. The application can correctly create an instance of that X509Certificate2 and use it for my requirements, however the problem arises when I try to use it in my azurewebsites web application.

Basically I can not access the certificates' PrivateKey instance variable, I get an exception

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist
```

And I am re-instantiating the certificate with this

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(myCertInBytes, myCertPass,
            X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
            X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
            X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

I am using ASPNET 5 rc1-update1. I have also tried running this on a different machine and it works fine, only have this issue when I publish to Azure. And to also add something else, This application was working when I was running the same project that was running using DNX version beta7

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the certificate in your database has the private key set included?  It's not a public cert by any chance, is it?

Comment: @ZainRizvi it is definitely included, I can retrieve the private key, (from the X509 Cert on Azure DB) if I run the key locally on-premises. However it cannot be retrieved when I deploy it to Azure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the Azure Web Apps restricts access to the machines private key store, since it's a shared hosting environment, and you don't fully own the machine. As a workaround, you can load a cert. This blog post describes the best practice on how to do so:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/

Please note that this only works for Basic Tier and above (not Free or Shared tier).

This can also be done from a .cer file as follows, however it should be noted that this is not best-practices since you're storing a secure credential with your code, in an insecure format.

```
public X509Certificate2 CertificateFromStrings(String certificateString64, String privateKeyXml)
{
    try
    {
        var rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml);

        var certificateBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certificateString64);
        var x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes);
        x509Certificate2.PrivateKey = rsaCryptoServiceProvider;

        return x509Certificate2;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the private key needs to be highly secured you could use the Azure Key Vault.

Comment: The thing is my code used to work 4 days ago and now it does not. So I was able to access my certs private key 4 days ago but not anymore. I have opted for this answers solution. To be honest I wish it was still possible on free tier so that mini throw-away projects could be hosted and still use X509 certs to sign things. I was forced to just upgrade my pricing plan for this web app.

Comment: Did you find a solution, @Lutando? I'm experiencing the same issue using Azure Key Vault. The code runs and works as expected when running on my localhost, but the same code in Azure App Service fails to instantiate the X509Certificate2 both when passing the password to the constructor and not.